# left join group by max - how to read record

Tags: php, mysql

I can't read record from column **data**, why?
Code:

```
$_query = mysqli_query($mysqli , "SELECT  o.id,o.surname,o.name,so.data FROM mowcy AS o
          LEFT JOIN zeb AS so ON so.id=o.id AND so.mowca=o.mowca 
           WHERE 
             o.archiwum = 0 
             AND o.id<>1
             AND o.mowca = 3

              GROUP BY o.id
               ORDER BY ISNULL(o.id) desc, MAX(so.data) ") 
                or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

shows an error:

> list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column
>   'rafik73_tereny.so.data' which is not functionally dependent on
>   columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this;

```
SELECT  o.id,MAX(so.data) FROM mowcy AS o
          LEFT JOIN zeb AS so ON so.id=o.id AND so.mowca=o.mowca 
           WHERE 
             o.archiwum = 0 
             AND o.id<>1
             AND o.mowca = 3
              GROUP BY o.id
               ORDER BY ISNULL(o.id) desc, MAX(so.data)
```

As the error directs to you when grouping something in your query, you should just select only **grouping fields and aggregated columns**.

Comment: **data** does not display any value. **data** exists only in the table **zeb**

Comment: Check your momcy data and where conditions. "o.archiwum = 0  AND o.id<>1  AND o.mowca = 3"

Comment: Conditions "o.archiwum = 0 AND o.id<>1 AND o.mowca = 3" are OK. When change MAX(so.data) to so.data in SELECT  and add so.data in GROUP BY values of **data** are displayed, but are duplicate.

Comment: Add alias **maxdata** to MAX(so.data) in SELECT solve problem. Thanks.